# how to change direction of text from ltr to rtl in docxtemplater?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docxtemplater

I'm inserting text into a Microsoft Word document using the docxtemplater module.

I'm having trouble inserting Arabic text.

```
doc.setData({
country: 'الهند'
});
```

output

[image]

Comment: What's the problem you're having with your code?

Comment: @JackBashford the text is flipped

Comment: So the problem is not inserting Arabic text but rather how to change direction of text from ltr to rtl (right to left)?

Comment: Docxtemplater not supported to add the direction style

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how to use the docxtemplater module, but the [`<w:rtl>`](https://docxtemplater.com/modules/html/#3-25-1) tag should help you. I'm not exactly sure how to implement the solution but something with this idea in mind might work (:

```js
country: '<w:rtl>الهند</w:rtl>'
```

(apologies if the above is invalid, I am not familiar with docxtemplater but have found the `<w:rtl>` tag and it seems to be what you're looking for.)

Comment: Thanks, @JackBashford. I try this but it's not working